# How to use celery to execute chain tasks regularly

Tags: python-2.7, celery

There are two tasks here.

```
@app.task(name='add')
def add(x, y):
    return x+y


@app.task(name='sub')
def sub(x, y):
    return x-y
```

Then use celery chain for these two tasks.(The version I am using is 4.20)

I want to time this celery chain

I have used it like this：

```
@app.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):  
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        20.0, chain(add.s(1, 9), sub.s(3)), name='run every 20s'
    )
```

But there is such an error：

```
NotImplementedError: chain is not a real task
```

What should I do,
How to time the celery chain,
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the chain in a regular task, and call it from the scheduler.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know what to do.